# how to show hide table in db2 ? table is created successfully but it's not showing in database

Tags: db2

How to show hide table in DB2? Table is created successfully but it's not showing in database. When I have created table and select schema and after that follow all process, table created successfully but it's not visible.
My query is:

```
CONNECT TO EMP;
CREATE TABLE DIGIT.DOC_MAST1_2030 ( DOC_CODE_2030 CHARACTER (6)  NOT NULL , DOC_NAME_2030 CHARACTER (75) , DOC_TLOC_2030 CHARACTER (1) , DOC_PLOC_2030 CHARACTER (75) , DOC_DLOC_2030 CHARACTER (75)   ) ;
CONNECT RESET;
```

Comment: Insufficient information in question. How do you know the statements are successful?  How do you test if the table exists? What do you mean, "it's not showing"?  What client tool are you using to submit the SQL? Did you commit the changes?  LEARN how to write a question properly.

Comment: Are you sure you committed this DDL? Try adding a COMMIT after the Create statement. Autocommit is default on the command line but depending on the tool used this might be different - and this would result in the symptoms described.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 provides a few ways to verify the existence of tables, views, and similar objects in a database.

From the Db2 command line processor: `LIST TABLES FOR SCHEMA DIGIT;`

From any client or SQL query tool: `SELECT TABNAME, TYPE, OWNER, CREATE_TIME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA='DIGIT';`

To verify you're looking in the right database, you can see which database you're currently accessing by running `VALUES CURRENT SERVER;`